# dynamic_cast causes segmentation violation in case of three level inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, dynamic-cast, polymorphism

It seems that `dynamic_cast` doesn't work in case of three-level inheritance.

The application crashes with Segmentation fault (core dumped) at the point of `print()` method invocation (in `main()`).

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>     //must be included to call any member functions for the typeinfo object returned by typeid()
using namespace std;
class CBase
{
public:
    virtual void print()
    {
        cout<<"CBase::print"<<endl;
    }
    virtual ~CBase()
    { }
};
class CDerivedA : public CBase
{
public:
    virtual void print()
    {
        cout<<"CDerivedA::print"<<endl;
    }
    virtual ~CDerivedA()
    {}
};
class CDerivedB : public CDerivedA
{
public:
    void print()
    {
        cout<<"CDerivedB::print"<<endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    CBase* ptrB = new CDerivedA();
    CDerivedB* ptrDB = dynamic_cast<CDerivedB*>(ptrB);
    ptrDB->print();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: details or didn't happen.

Comment: perfect example of how not to write a question on SO

Comment: show your code, show the compiler error message...

Comment: Looking at your code, I would say that it works, and it returns `NULL` exactly as it should. Did you intend to write `new CDerivedB`?

Comment: @molbdnilo: no, I just want to know if the object's type that base pointer(ptrB) points must be CDerivedB. it looks more like downcasting that we often did, but there're actually the different things. do you think of the way that downcasting in this example is impossible?

Answer (score 4):

A "pointer which points to a CDerivedA" (base class) cannot be cast to a "pointer to CDerivedB" (derived class). Note that I don't mean the *declared pointer type*; the problem is that the *real object pointed-to* is in fact an instance of the base class, thus the [downcast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting) cannot succeed.

`dynamic_cast` returns a `null`-pointer in case of a failed downcast, which could be the reason for segmentation violation (in case of casting a reference it would throw a `bad_cast` exception).

Note that `dynamic_cast` requires [RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTTI) (run-time type information) to work correctly. RTTI can be turned off in compiler for performance reasons (as it introduces some overhead at runtime if enabled). Please double-check that you have RTTI enabled in your compiler.

**EDIT:** regarding your last comment -

### Basics of Downcasting

You can't downcast an instance of base class. You can downcast a pointer declared as "pointer-to-base-class", which is in fact pointing to an instance of a derived class. An example of how you may use downcasting:

```
class Base 
{ public:
  virtual void baseMethod() {cout<<"baseMethod in Base"<<endl;} 
  // I am omitting virtual destructors here for brevity, 
  // which you should _not_ do in your code! 
}
class Derived : public Base 
{ public:
  void baseMethod() {cout<<"baseMethod in Derived"<<endl;} 
  virtual void derivedMethod(){cout<<"derivedMethod in Derived"<<endl;} 
}
class Derived2 : public Derived 
{ public:
  void baseMethod() {cout<<"baseMethod in Derived2"<<endl;} 
  void derivedMethod(){cout<<"derivedMethod in Derived2"<<endl;} 
  void derived2Method(){cout<<"derived2Method in Derived2"<<endl;} 
} 

void someFunction(Base* pBase) 
{ 
  // pBase may actually point to an instance of Base, Derived or Derived2. 
  // But you can invoke only 'baseMethod' on pBase, 
  // since 'derivedMethod' and 'derived2Method' are not declared in Base. 

  pBase->baseMethod(); // ok

  // ERROR: pBase->derivedMethod(); 
  // ERROR: pBase->derived2Method(); 

  // To invoke 'derivedMethod', you have to downcast to Derived: 
  Derived* pDerived = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(pBase); 
  if(pDerived /* != null */) 
  { 
    // Downcast successful, i.e. 
    // pBase actually points to an instance of Derived _or_ Derived2. 
    // Both have the 'derivedMethod', so you can invoke it via 'pDerived' pointer: 

    pDerived->derivedMethod(); // ok 

    // ERROR: pDerived->derived2Method(); 

    // To call 'derived2Method', you have to downcast to Derived2. 
  } 
  else 
  { 
    // If we are here, then dynamic_cast returned null, 
    // i.e. the downcast was NOT successful 
    // and pBase actually points to an instance of Base. 
  } 

}
```

### Avoid casts

You should try to design your program so that casts are not necessary. 
Use polymorphism instead. 
Declare all needed methods in base classes. Use [pure virtual methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function#Abstract_classes_and_pure_virtual_functions).

### Upgrading Base to Derived

You cannot *upgrade* instances via casting. 
If you want to upgrade an instance of `Base` to an instance of `Derived`, 
then you must define a constructor in `Derived` which takes Base as argument, and create a new instance of Derived via `new`. Note that old instance of `Base` stays as it was, only a new instance of `Derived` is created.

```
class Derived : public Base 
{ public:

  Derived(Base& base) 
    : Base(base) // use copy constructor of Base 
  {
    // initializations specific to Derived
  } 

  // ... other methods ... 
}


// Usage: 
Base* pBase = new Base(); 
Derived* pDerived = new Derived(*pBase); // "upgrade" Base to Derived. 

// The instance of Base (pointed to by pBase) still lives, 
// and a new instance of Derived (pointed to by pDerived) is born. 

// Do not forget to delete both pBase and pDerived!
```

---

I hope this helps.

Many thanks to [Tadeusz Kopec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113662/tadeusz-kopec) for correction.

Comment: it looks more like that I intentionally downcast an instance of base class. as i read the think in cplusplus recently. those statements really confuse me. how might source_pointer's type be the base class of destination*'s?                                                    "For a dynamic_cast<destination*>(source_pointer), most cases are quite straightforward: 
source_pointer ’s RTTI information is retrieved, and RTTI information for the type 
destination* is fetched. Then a library routine determines whether  source_pointer ’s type is 
of type destination* or a base class of  destination*. "

Comment: many thanks for your good example. the so-called downcasting just means the pointer from base class to derived class, in actually, the objects that pointer points-to are performed "upcasting", thus it could guarantee a complete object. do you agree?

Comment: @yao: "downcasting just means _the pointer_ from base class to derived class" - exactly,  and actually, the object that pointer points-to is _not changed_ in any way.

Comment: @yao: *upcasting* is conversion from pointer-to-derived-type to pointer-to-base-type. This does *not* require an *explicit* cast C++, e.g.: `Derived* pDerived = new Derived(); Base* pBase = pDerived;` Note that the object-pointed-to is still an instance of `Derived`, it is *not* degraded to `Base`. Upcasting is always safe and always succeeds.

Comment: it's not degraded to Base, but it just could invoke the member functions of Base class. it's implemented by Compiler somehow. definitely, all the rules are created by complier. thanks for your comments:)